# Drawing Text on Right Side of NSImage - Unwanted Spacing

Tags: swift, macos, swift4, nsimage

I'm using the following code to draw text on the right side on an image

```
         im.lockFocus()
         if let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext {
         context.saveGState()
         let size = text.size(withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
         context.translateBy(x: imageRect.width-size.height, y: (imageRect.height - size.width) / 2)
         context.rotate(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)
         text.draw(at: .zero, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
         context.restoreGState()
         im.unlockFocus()
```

As you can see there is some excessive spacing from the right side.How can i fix it?

[image]

Update:

```
class DemoView: NSView {
    override func draw(_ rect: NSRect) {

        // .. your drawing code here

        NSColor.red.set()  // just for demo
        rect.fill()        // just for demo

        if let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext {
            context.saveGState()

            let text: NSString = "Hello World"
            let attributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.white, 
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)
            ]

            let size = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)
            context.translateBy(x: imageRect.width-size.height, y: (rect.height - size.width) / 2)
            context.rotate(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)

            text.draw(at: .zero, withAttributes: attributes)

            context.restoreGState()
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
This is the desired result
[image]

Comment: Is this spacing present if you remove `text.draw(at: .zero, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)` ?

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk If i remove that code,how will the drawing be done?

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that `text.draw` is the only drawing code here. My point is, that this is not the text which causes the bug. Also, could you provide the whole function, not just the body?

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk Please see the update

Comment: Is the question still actual?

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk Yes,please see the latest comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following translation

[image: demo]

```
context.translateBy(x: self.bounds.maxX, y: (rect.height - size.width) / 2)
```

Comment: I'm drawing on an NSImage.. please see the first code snippet.It has no property bounds

Comment: @techno, if you draw over image then use `x: imageRect.width`

Comment: Thanks ... could you tell me how to place the text such that the bottom part of the text points towards the center of the image rather than resting on the border.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you understand how CGContext transforms work, if not, learn it.

One of the simplest implementations of your problem is like this: the text is blue rectangle, you want to draw a red rectangle.

[image]

So it's enough to calculate a shift transform, then rotate-90. 
A shift transform in this case is a left-bottom of the blue rectangle, and at the same time the right-bottom of the red rectangle.

Your `DemoView` can look like this:

```
class DemoView: NSView {
    override func draw(_ rect: NSRect) {

        let image = NSImage(named: "test_image.jpg")!

        if let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext {
            context.saveGState()

            NSColor.red.set()  // just for demo
            rect.fill()        // just for demo

            image.draw(in: rect)

            let text: NSString = "Hello World"
            let attributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSColor.white,
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)
            ]

            let size = bounds.size
            let rotatedTextCenter = CGPoint(x: size.width*0.8, y: size.height/2)

            // draw the the circle in desired center to check if text was transformed correctly
            drawCircleInView(context: context, center: rotatedTextCenter)

            // draw the rotated text so its center fits the circle center
            drawAttributedTextInView(text: text, textAttributes: attributes, context: context, viewSize: size, centerInView: rotatedTextCenter)

            context.restoreGState()
        }
    }

    func drawCircleInView(context: CGContext, center: CGPoint) {
        context.setLineWidth(5)
        context.setFillColor(NSColor.red.cgColor)
        context.addArc(center: center, radius: 10, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi*2, clockwise: false)
        context.fillPath()
    }

    func drawAttributedTextInView(text: NSString,
                                  textAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key:Any],
                                  context: CGContext,
                                  viewSize: CGSize,
                                  centerInView textCenter: CGPoint) {

        // we assume everything else was already drawn and context has identity transform for the simplicity

        let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: textAttributes)

        context.translateBy(x: textCenter.x+textSize.height/2, y: textCenter.y-textSize.width/2)
        context.rotate(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)

        text.draw(at: .zero, withAttributes: textAttributes)
    }
}
```

In this code, the `centerInView` param is the center of your red rectangle.

The result looks like this:
[image]

Please note that we fill the entire view with red color, then we render the image, then we render the text. 
No excessive spacing is present. If it was present, we would see red lines *below* the image.

You can download the demo [here](https://github.com/gatamar/stackoverflow_answers/tree/master/so61676256).

And please don't draw *everything* in a one `draw(_ rect: NSRect)` call - try to extract at least the text drawing func - it'll give you much more flexibility in defining the variables of the problem.

**UPDATE**:

I you need the text to be "flipped", so its bottom side points toward the center, the transform can look like this:

```
context.translateBy(x: textCenter.x-textSize.height/2, y: textCenter.y+textSize.width/2)
context.rotate(by: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

and the text will look like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, will learn about the method in detail.The spacing i was referring to is between the text and the image border.The spacing exists in your preview image.

Comment: @techno So does the problem with spacing still exist?

Comment: I was referring to the image you posted.The text has some space from the right side of the image.

Comment: @techno No sure if I've understood your problem, but I updated the answer - hope it will be useful